# Lumia 550 Microsoft sound problem

Tags: windows-10-mobile, audio, lumia-550

When I plug in my headphones, no sound except "pop pop pop" softly? I was trying to play music from the album list.

Comment: Are these headphones, or a headset with microphone?

Comment: Do you use branded headsets?Check whether the headset works on other mobiles!